# Como acessar jTextField estatico criado com swing?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, swing, jtextfield

Então galera eu tenho um `jTextField` que funciona normalmente porém quando eu coloco ele como `static` o `setText` não funciona mais, e preciso dele estático pois passo o mesmo para uma função, fiz isso sem o `swing` e funcionou não sei o que esta acontecendo agora.

Segue abaixo o codigo:

```
//Codigo gerado automaticamento pelo swing

public static javax.swing.JTextField blueBGolem;

blueBGolem.setEditable(false);
blueBGolem.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
blueBGolem.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
blueBGolem.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
blueBGolem.setText("5:00");
blueBGolem.setBorder(null);
blueBGolem.setOpaque(false);
Painel.add(blueBGolem);
blueBGolem.setBounds(0, 0, 70, 17);


private void blueBGolemStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    //timerBlueBGolem.start();
    blueBGolem.setText("ooi");
}
```

### EDIT

Acho que é algo no meu codigo mais não consigo achar o que..

segue o codigo completo

http://pastebin.com/Rat9QA9j

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro? Não acho que usar static seja a melhor solução para o problema. Especifique melhor o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: @JodsonLeandro Não há mensagem de erro simplesmente ao clicar no jbutton nada acontece

Comment: @JodsonLeandro eu preciso passar o meu jtextfield para uma função onde o mesmo vai ser alterado e para fazer isso ele tem de ser estatico

Comment: @alleen94 Ele não precisa ser estático. Se você passar o objeto por parâmetro no método, você vai ter a instância. Eu não me recordo em qual estrutura o swing foi feita, mas você pode validar se a instância do seu JTextField está sendo sempre a mesma.

Comment: @JodsonLeandro o netbeans não me deixa passar se o objeto nao for estatico

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que as suas variáveis não são estáticas, é só colocar como estático que resolve seu problema.

Se estiver usando o NetBeans e a opção de "arrastar componentes" configura conforme abaixo:

[image: NetBeans]

Caso esteja fazendo manualmente os componentes acrescenta static nas variaveis:

```
public javax.swing.JTextField blueBGolem; // anterior
public static javax.swing.JTextField blueBGolem; // novo
```

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de tornar o seu JTextField estático. O que menciona sobre passar um JTextField como argumento para um método pode ser feito sem que o JTextField seja estático a menos que o método alvo seja um método estático, como o public static void main(String[] args).

Caso esteja a usar o JTextField dentro do método main, experimente declarar o JTextfield apenas dentro do método main em vez de o declarar como variável de instância da classe.